# Convert IP to hostname from a file with perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to convert IP's to hostnames via file using perl (without using built in Socket function). 
My file looks like this:

```
192.168.1.1    firewall
192.168.2.4    wifi
192.168.3.10   switch
```

My code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $input_dns_file='./file';
our %ip2host_hash;
sub read_dns_file()
{
        open(DNS_FILE,'<',$input_dns_file) or die;
        while ( my $line=<DNS_FILE> ){
                my ($ip,$hostname) = split(/\s+/,$line,2);
                $ip2host_hash{$ip} = $hostname;
        }
```

The problem is that the hash always return the first line of the file. How do I fill the hash `%ip2host` so it can return every hostname when I enter the IP address?

Comment: Are you sure the hash contains what you says it does? (Use `Data::Dumper` and `print Dumper(\%your_hash)` to see its content.) What you have there looks fine.

Comment: Maybe you want to support multiple hostnames with one IP?

Comment: Failed to get your question, sorry: what do you mean by 'the hash always returns'? Your code seems well legit: you're going through the file line by line, filling the map...

Comment: Also note that by not `chomp`ing `line`, you'll end up with a `\n` at the end of each hostname. This may not be what you want.

Comment: It would be far better to write simply `my ($ip, $hostname) = split;` as this would avoid the need for `chomp`ing the input records, and would deal with any leading and trailing whitespace as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a script to extract a hostname from a list (on file), given the IP. This is simple. Here's a one-liner:

```
perl -wle '
     $ip = shift; 
     %list = map split,<>; 
     print $list{$ip} || "$ip not found";
' 192.168.2.24 list_of_ips
```

`-l` will chomp the input and add a newline to print (for convenience). `map` will just split each element in the input list, so it fits with a hash structure. The last statement will print the hostname, if it is found, or an error if not.

Here's a script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ip = shift;
my $file = "list_of_ips";

open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
my %list = map split, <$fh>;
print $list{$ip} || "$ip not found\n";
```

What you may consider is using a short circuit, to return as soon as a match is found. This will be better from a performance point of view, especially with large input files.

```
while (<$fh>) {
    my ($num, $host) = split;
    if ($num eq $ip) {
        print $host;
        last;
    }
}
```